# Converting Telerik DockingManager to RadDock

Tags: winforms, telerik, raddocking

DockingManager control has been removed from their suite in Q1 2011, so now I am looking to replace it with their new control called RadDock. I followed update notes [here](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/whats-new/dock-q2-2009-beta.aspx) (section "Updating your project") but after completing the conversion I am left with a new blank RadDock object and the original DockingManager object (together with the elements it contained) stuck in behind of it.

I've then tried dragging different elements onto the new RadDock, but none of them will dock.

Has anyone else had similar issues while upgrading this control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik support sent me a video step by step explaining how to do the conversion. Not sure how long the link will work, but [HERE](http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/367570_Untitled.zip) it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this scenario and on my the the DockingManager is successfully converted to RadDock and the content of the windows is right in place.